# Print list in specific way in Python

Tags: python, list, printing, format

I have a list like this

```
list=[[2,3],[3,4]]
```

I want to print each list in the list like this:
1: 2 3, 2: 3 4
So the first part is the position of the list in the list followed by the numbers in the list. 
So far i've tried a for loop and a single print line. The for loop works but prints every list in a new line. The other print statement looks like this but it doesn't work at all and i have no idea how to fix it.

```
print('{0:}:'.format(list[0]),' '.join([', '.join([str(e) for e in slist]) for slist in list]))
```

For this the list looked like this `list = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]` so the first element in each list is the index for the list (starts at 1)
I use Python3

Comment: using list a variable name is bad practice

Comment: it's just for the question here. but thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l =[[2,3],[3,4]]
print(", ".join(["{}: {}".format(ind," ".join(map(str,x))) for ind, x in enumerate(l,1)]))
1: 2 3, 2: 3 4
```

`enumerate(l,1)` keeps track of the index of the sublists, we pass `1` as the second parameter to start the indexing at `1` instead of `0.

`" ".join(map(str,x)` maps  all the ints to strings and we use `str.format` to  add `:` before each index. `", ".join` separates each section with a comma.

Comment: @iCodez, lol yes I suppose it does, there does not seem to be any simple way to do it. I will add some explanation though :).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `join()` and [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) in a list comprrehension :

```
>>> l=[[2,3],[3,4]]
>>> ','.join(['{}:{}'.format(i,' '.join(str(t) for t in j)) for i,j in enumerate(l,1)])
'1:2 3,2:3 4'
```